# How Spring Session Variables work

Tags: java, forms, spring, session, spring-mvc

How do spring mvc request-scoped session variables work?

For example, suppose a user wants to modify some 'Foo' objects from his/her browser, and opens up multiple tabs to do so: e.g.,

```
HTTP-GET/tab#1: http://mywebsite.com/foo/edit?id=1
HTTP-GET/tab#2: http://mywebsite.com/foo/edit?id=2
```

and both get submitted via

```
HTTP-POST/URL = http://mywebsite.com/foo/save
```

No "id" information is stored anywhere on the client-side (except just in the URL query string the client accesses to modify the desired "Foo" object), nor transmitted back to the server.

How does Spring MVC know that a submission from tab#1 is supposed to modify Foo#1, and a submission from tab#2 is supposed to modify Foo#2? (i.e., so the fields on a particular edit form from a particular tab bind to the correct Foo object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you'll run into a form-object race condition trying to edit what might seem like two different objects from two different tabs. When you open tab#2 to edit "Foo#2", a submission from tab#1 will actually modify Foo#2 (not the expected Foo#1). Then, of course, you'll run into an optimistic lock failure trying to submit from the second tab...

So yes, you will have to send some 'id' information back to the server to tell it which 'Foo' object to update. Some hidden form fields backed by an HMAC seem to be the approach to do that...

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are ususally saved as cookies or hidden input fields. For example `<input type="hidden" value="#SESSIONID" />` is send too if a user has a open session. These sessionsids are mapped with objects and variables on the server.

Comment: Cookies and sessionid's are irrelevant here, since I'm trying to distinguish between different objects for the same user, not different users' objects.
Also, my question says no object "id" information is sent back to the server, so the hidden object id fields don't really work either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the id anywhere in the form (immutable or hidden field) or better bind an entity to the form as a [form backing object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697778/spring-mvc-generating-a-form-backing-object-from-a-request). Tabs in the same browser share the same session.

Comment: So, if I use "form-backing objects", SpringMVC can tell which object to update simply based on the tab I send the request from? Even without any submitting any "id" information back to the server?

Comment: The id needs to be kept somewhere in the request or in the session. Either as a form parameter or as a field in the backing object.

Comment: Will this will work even if *only* the form-backing object (not the browser form) knows the 'id' ?